# Skip a blank line when reading a file in python using readline

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, readline

My program parses different types of log files and some of them have empty lines at the beginning of a file. Getting a variable for the first line is very important in this program. I've figured out how to make it skip over the blank lines but I haven't been able to make it treat the first line with text as the real first line. My code is as follows

```
 if first_line.find('Chain') != -1:
    first_time = int(searchforfirsttime.group(2)
```

My after that I need an else statement that makes first_line = the second line of the file.
Thanks.

Edit:

The first few lines of the file I am reading is

```
(Blank Line)
CODE: 30;  Chain 1;  Time = 92473622;   PASSIVE:; 127; 127; 127; 127;   ACTIVE:; 127; 127; 127; 127; 127; 127; 127; 127; 127; 127;   CAPS:; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;   DELAYS:;   0; 0; 0; 0;
CODE:31;  Chain1:;  Time = 92473765;  DCInputPower = -28.587273; DCOutputPower = -23.745722; DCCoeffs:  I:0; Q:0I:0; Q:0I:0; Q:0I:0;
```

Comment: Can you give us the first few lines of the file?

Comment: How are you obtaining the first line? I would think that most of the time, the exact same bit of code will work to get the second link and put it in `first_line`.

Comment: Unrelated to the main problem, I suggest replacing `if first_line.find('Chain') != -1:` with `if 'Chain' in first_line:`

Comment: Do you want to skip only the first blank lines or all the blank lines, including the ones in the middle or at the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anish Shah has a great answer <s>if you can fit your file in memory</s> (EDIT: and now he has a great answer for both cases). If you can't, you can always try a `while` loop to keep looping until you find a first line and assign `first_time`.

```
first_time = None
while first_time is None:
  first_line = file.readline()
  if first_line.find('Chain') != -1:
     first_time = int(searchforfirsttime.group(2))
```

I assume you're using `readline()` to get that first line.

This is one thing I like about Python, is the dynamic typing. `first_time` can be anything, really, so we can start with a value that `int()` will never return. That guarantees that we don't leave until it worked.

Comment: Now it's my time to nitpick :-) The [programming recommendations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) from PEP 8 say that "comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators". So replace `first_time == None` with `first_time is None`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu and a fair nitpick it was. Answer has been changed.

Answer (score 4):

```
lines = filter(None, (line.rstrip() for line in open(logfile)))
```

This gives you list of all non-empty lines of your file.

**UPDATE:**

If you're having memory contraints, then you can use [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) which returns a generator instead of list - suggested by [CristianCiupit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12892/cristian-ciupitu)

Comment: To stop [TheSoundDefense](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24743575/12892) from complaining about the memory usage, it wouldn't hurt to add a generator based solution, e.g. one that uses [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) or generator comprehension.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Yes! haha. I was just going to add that in my answer. I didn't consider memory thing before. Thanks!

Comment: @CristianCiupitu but I like complaining about memory usage... in any case, creating a generator of non-blank lines is probably the best solution. You could plug it right into your existing code with almost no changes to other parts of it.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, complaints make us improve :-)

Comment: This worked but form my situation TheSoundDefense had the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing an ASCII text file, you should be able to do the following:

```
LogFilePathNameString = '/path/to/log/file/LogFileName.log';

FirstLineString = '';
FirstLineIndex = 0;

with open( LogFilePathNameString, 'r' ) as LogFileObject:

    LogFileObjectLineStringsList = LogFileObject.readlines();

    NumFileLines = len( LogFileObjectLineStringsList );

    for i in range( 0, NumFileLines, 1 ):

        CurrentLineString = LogFileObjectLineStringsList[ i ];

        if ( CurrentLine != '\n' ):

           FirstLineString = CurrentLineString;
           FirstLineIndex = i;
           break;

        #fi

    #rof

#hitw

print ( 'Found ' + str(FirstLineString) + ' on Line ' + str(FirstLineIndex) '.' );
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to remove some of the blank lines and the `#end-of-block` comments. I.e. make the code more Pythonic and [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant.